# Permutation....or similar to that

Tags: c#, loops, permutation, combinations, nested

I have this array of char: `private char[] posibilities = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };`

And I want all possible combination of them, then I made three nested for:

```
for (int cont = 0; cont < posibilities.Length; cont++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < posibilities.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < posibilities.Length; j++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(posibilities[cont].ToString() + posibilities[i].ToString() + posibilities[j].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: How can I do something in case that I want to add more chars to my array without adding more fors to my nested for? Imagine if I have 20 chars on the array, I can't do 20 for....or that is the only way?

(By the way, I have been trying to solve this since 3 months ago, and still I can't)

Comment: the result has to be like this:
aaa
aab
aac
aba
abb
...
ccb
ccc

Comment: You may want to look into using recursion for this

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Just for reference, what you're asking for is all of the *permutations with repetition*, "combinations" are different than "permutations"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this recursive approach:

```
void RecursiveApproach(char[] possibilities, string cur)
{
    if (cur.Length == c.Length)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(cur);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < possibilities.Length; i++)
    {
        RecursiveApproach(possibilities, cur + possibilities[i]);
    }
}

// Usage
RecursiveApproach(possibilities, "");
```

listBox1 can be passed as third parameter to this function if it is impossible to make it global visible.

But be careful with large numbers, this list will grow VERY fast))

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to mix algorithms with UI interactions.  It would be preferable to have the permutation generator return (rather than be void) some collection or sequence of all of the permutations and then have separate UI code that calls that method and does...whatever with it.

Comment: Servy, you are right, BUT you need to choose right tool for the job. This guy was clearly asking about light weight solution to fit his needs. He did not want a universal pattern like approach for multicombinations. He did not know how to use to use recursion and I showed it for him, now he can adopt it for his needs (UI or something)

Comment: Actually I am learning c#, and about recursion the only thing that I know is to make the factorial, so thanks again Servy, I am trying to gain experience little by little.

Comment: @SergeyS Bad practices are much easier to learn than to un-learn.  While it makes the implementation of this method easier, it makes *using* this method *much* harder, as you need to do a copy/paste, change stuff each time you want to use it.  That's poor design.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> PermutationsWithRepitition<T>(IList<T> source)
{
    return PermutationsWithRepitition(source, source.Count);
}

//private recursive method that does all of the work.
private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> PermutationsWithRepitition<T>(IList<T> source, int resultSize)
{
    if (resultSize == 1)
        return source.Select(item => new[] { item });
    else
    {
        return PermutationsWithRepitition(source, resultSize - 1)
            .SelectMany(permutation => source.Select(item => new[]{item}.Concat(permutation)));
    }
}
```

example usage:

```
char[] posibilities = new[] { 'a', 'b', 'c' };

foreach (var permutation in PermutationsWithRepitition(posibilities))
{
    Console.WriteLine(new string(permutation.ToArray()));
}
```

Comment: Looks like overkill here. Guy is just started to learn C# and you want him to run away??))

Comment: @SergeyS No, I simply want to encourage good practices from the start, rather than enabling poor practices that result in significant problems down the road.

Comment: Imagine, you have just created your first desktop app in C#, you have no idea about Lync and many other stuff. You asked trivial algorithmical question (!) and you receive such an answer as yours.

Comment: @Servy I have copied your code and I am trying to understand it, I have no clue what you have made there, but believe me, I will try to understand it. Thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: @SergeyS There's your flawed premise; it's not a trivial algorithmic question.  The operation itself requires more knowledge then a brand new programmer has to properly implement.  If I was teaching someone how to program I wouldn't give them such a task right away.

Comment: @Servy, just one last silly question, how do I call this code? I know for you may be logic, but again, I have no clue what you did here.

Comment: @user1821732 Added an example usage.

Comment: @Servy works fantastic!, the way that works definitely is not how I have imagined (because I don't not good c#) Thanks to you two guys, you really make my day today!

Comment: @user1821732 That's the idea here.  This method is a fair bit more complex in it's implementation than other answers, but it is specifically to make calling it *much* easier.  Until you learn more (although I dislike doing this, there really isn't much choice under the circumstances) you should forgo trying to understand what this method does.  Just treat it as a black box until you learn more and can come back to it.